# Inconsistent flexbox CSS with fieldsets, Firefox vs. Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, flexbox, fieldset

I've encountered some weird behavior that I would appreciate getting explained or cleared up. Am I perhaps using flex wrong?

https://jsfiddle.net/bxnohfkq/5/

```js
let $field = $('#field');
let $wrapper = $('#wrapper');
let $button = $('#button');

// display dimensions.
$field.val($wrapper.outerWidth() + '×' + $wrapper.outerHeight());

// ???
$button.click((ev) => {
  if ($wrapper.is('.fix')) {
    $wrapper.removeClass('fix');
  } else {
    $wrapper.addClass('fix');
  }
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

fieldset {
  min-width: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
}

#wrapper {
  max-width: 260px;
}

#padded {
  padding: 0.5rem;
  background-color: tan;
}

#row {
  display: flex;
}

#fieldset_field {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

#field {
  width: 100%;
}

#button {
  margin-left: 0.5rem;
}

.fix fieldset {
  min-inline-size: unset;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <p>Clicking button fixes the issue in Firefox. In Chrome, it never even comes up in the first place.</p>
  <div id="padded">
    <div id="row">
      <fieldset id="fieldset_field">
        <input type="text" id="field" />
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset id="fieldset_button">
        <button id="button">Ok</button>
      </fieldset>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have an input field that pushes a neighboring button out of its wrapper box – but only in Firefox; Chrome doesn't have that issue.

At first, I thought it had something to do with how the user agents use different default widths for the form input field. But it turned out to be a `<fieldset>` setting: it aligns nicely if I apply `min-inline-size: unset;` or `min-inline-size: min-content;` to all fieldsets.

Though, I do not really understand the underlying issue. [Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min-inline-size) suggests that that attribute only ever becomes relevant in regards to the writing direction – which I'm not changing in any way.

Comment: @G-Cyrillus, you need to resize the window.

Comment: @Simplicius okay, i see, funny indeed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use `flex: 1 1 0;` (`flex: [grow] [shrink] [base];`) instead of only `flex-grow: 1;`, this way you can also remove the `min-inline-size`.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
fieldset {
  min-width: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
}
#wrapper {
  max-width: 260px;
}
#padded {
  padding: 0.5rem; 
  background-color: tan;
}
#row {
  display: flex; 
}
#fieldset_field {
  flex: 1 1 0;
}
#field {
  width: 100%;
}
#button {
  margin-left: 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <p>Clicking button fixes the issue in Firefox. In Chrome, it never even comes up in the first place.</p>
  <div id="padded">
    <div id="row">
      <fieldset id="fieldset_field">
        <input type="text" id="field" />
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset id="fieldset_button">
        <button id="button">Ok</button>
      </fieldset>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You're right, this does fix it. (Base 0, huh? Okay) I don't know why this works but since flex is a mysterium of itself to me, I'll accept this answer.

Comment: @WoodrowShigeru. Haha, `base: 0` is the synonym for *unset*.